# enableBrowserColor function is not working in angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How can I change the browser color in angular material using script without using meta tag

```
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('amazingPaletteName', {

        'contrastDefaultColor': 'light', 

        'contrastDarkColors': ['50', '100', 
            '200', '300', '400', 'A100'
        ],
        'contrastLightColors': undefined 
    }),


        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
  .primaryPalette('amazingPaletteName');


$mdThemingProvider.enableBrowserColor({
    theme: 'defualt',
    palette: 'default'      

});

});
```

the above code return some error 
enableBrowserColor is not a function

Comment: Why would you want to do it without doing it the right way?

Comment: .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('amazingPaletteName', {

        'contrastDefaultColor': 'light', 

        'contrastDarkColors': ['50', '100', 
            '200', '300', '400', 'A100'
        ],
        'contrastLightColors': undefined 
    }),


        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
  .primaryPalette('amazingPaletteName');


$mdThemingProvider.enableBrowserColor({
    theme: 'defualt',
    palette: 'default'      

});

});  the above code  return error (enableBrowserColor is not a function)

Comment: This feature is mobile only.